# Connection hanged using transaction suspension with Websphere datasource

Tags: sql-server, websphere, datasource, spring-transactions

While using websphere datasource to connect SQL-SERVER spring transaction getting hanged (Locked) with REQUIRES_NEW or NOT_SUPPORTED propogations.

This is not the case when using BasicDataSource or any other.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe you have uncommitted work from another transaction.   Either do it all in one tran, commit the other tran, or change the locks.  If that's not helpful you'll need to provide more detail in your question.

Answer (score 0):

REQUIRES_NEW and NOT_SUPPORTED are both transaction attributes that would prevent running the operation in the current transaction (which would be suspended and then resumed afterwards).  The WebSphere Application Server data source is aware of container managed transactions and will enlist in them.  I'm not sure what BasicDataSource is, but if it is not aware of container transactions, that could explain why you see a difference in behavior.

The flow to cause a single-thread deadlock could be something like this:

- transaction begin
- SQL command that locks row X
- invoke REQUIRES_NEW method
- implies transaction suspend, new transaction begin
- SQL command that attempts to lock row X  <-- deadlock here

If this is what you are seeing, it is operating as designed, per spec, and you should consider using a different transaction attribute, such as SUPPORTS, if you want the operation to run in the same transaction.